# What it means "..." in this code?

Tags: java, eclipse

```
public class AcademGroup implements Serializable {
Student[] students;

AcademGroup(Student... st) {
    this.students = st;
}
```

What it means "Student... st"?
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the ellipsis operator.

It means you can pass an arbitrary number of arguments to your method/constructor when calling it. E.g.:

```
new AcademGroup(student1);
new AcademGroup(student1, student2);
new AcademGroup(student1, student2, student3);
```

etc.
In the method/constructor's code it's treated as an array.

Answer (score 2):

It means varargs. Any count of
students you can pass in there.

So you can call it like this

```
new AcademGroup();
```

or

```
new AcademGroup(st);
```

or

```
new AcademGroup(st1, st2);
```

or

```
new AcademGroup(st1, st2, st3);
```

and so on, i.e. with 0,1,2,3, etc. 
Student objects as parameters.

Comment: Or `new AcademGroup();`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun Good remark :)

Answer (score 1):

It means that you can pass any amount of `Student` in there and `st` will result in an array or a sequence of `Student`.